# How to use capacitorjs to connect send two separate audio streams over bluetooth

Tags: ios, vue.js, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, capacitor-plugin

I have not been able to find an answer to this with any of my research despite already starting my project. I have a vuejs w/quasar application setup with two audio files stored on my project. I am able to play each of them using the html5 audio tag. However, this application will be deployed to a iOS application using capacitorjs which is integrated into quasar cli by default. So I have already enabled that and it works in the simulator very well. My issue is I cannot find any resources regarding if this bluetooth option is possible. So first, can capitorjs allow a device to send an separate audio stream to two separate connected bluetooth devices?

I found the following library :

https://github.com/capacitor-community/bluetooth-le

And it handles the bluetooth connections in capacitorjs but there is no examples of connecting to more than one device. Its actually very limited examples. So can you direct data which data goes to which bluetooth device similar to what i am trying to accomplish but with audio only. I have read with bluetooth 5 you can connect to multiple bluetooth so newer iphones should be able to achieve this from a technical perspective I would assume.

Lastly, if this is possible, what is a simple example showing this exercise with capacitorjs library? Also, I am aware I am not able to test bluetooth in the xCode simulator so I will need to deploy to a real device to try this out.

Comment: Apps don't use Bluetooth directly for audio playback. They just play audio via the AV framework and the system audio route is used.  I don't believe that iOS allows you to have two active Bluetooth audio routes at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible on iOS. capacitorjs isn't relevant here. A framework can't do anything the OS doesn't allow.

There is [multi-route support](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionBasics/AudioSessionBasics.html), but it is very limited and [does not support Bluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfaudio/avaudiosessioncategoryoptions/avaudiosessioncategoryoptionallowbluetootha2dp):

> Audio sessions using the `multiRoute` or `record` categories implicitly clear [the `allowBluetoothA2DP`] option. If you clear [`allowBluetoothA2DP`], paired Bluetooth A2DP devices don’t show up as available audio output routes.

Note that the bluetooth-le library you've linked is only for Bluetooth LE, which does not handle audio at all. (There is such a thing as "Bluetooth LE Audio," but as with so many things in the Bluetooth world, despite having a similar name it is a completely different protocol, and iOS apps have no access to it, and I don't believe any iPhones support it yet in any case.)

Comment: Rob thank you for this clarification. Just out of curiosity does android support this unlike iOS? If not, would you have any recommendation on how to approach this problem and maybe a mobile app is not the right idea. The purpose of this project is a gift for my father. He wanted an app that could play one song on one bluetooth device and another song on another bluetooth device. Maybe I shouldnt have done it as a mobile app and went a different route all together. Its a fun project but I just am not sure which direction to go in then if iOS doesnt support it. Thank you

Comment: I don't believe that's possible on Android either. This answer matches my experience: https://superuser.com/a/1790493/15188  I believe you would need two Bluetooth hardware stacks (specifically, you'd likely need another antenna, particularly if the device uses the same antenna for both WiFi and Bluetooth, which is common). With some devices (Samsung Dual Audio, for example), it is possible to send the *same* stream to two devices, but not different streams. (Similarly, wireless earbuds and hearing aids are examples of "same stream to multiple devices." It's trickier than it sounds....)

Comment: The usual way to approach this problem is a smart speaker with its own WiFi. So the speaker plays the audio itself, and the app just controls the speaker (possibly transferring it data over WiFi rather than Bluetooth, but not **streaming** the data in realtime, which is hard).